# why does my column become vertical, not as design?

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie with HTML CSS and here is my problem.

I coded a very simple HTML CSS program and here is my HTML CSS program

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
            .col {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #ccc;
            background-clip: content-box;
            margin-top: 8px;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
            body {
            margin: 0;
            }
            .container {
            text-align: center;
            }
            .course-item {
            background-color: orange;
            height: 260px;
            }
            h1 {
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 260px;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
      <body>
      <div class="grid wide container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col l-3">
                <div class="course-item">
                    <h1>course 1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col l-3">
                <div class="course-item">
                    <h1>course 2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col l-3">
                <div class="course-item">
                    <h1>course 3</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col l-3">
                <div class="course-item">
                    <h1>course 4</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </body>
      </html>
```

Here is my css program

```css
    .grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .grid.wide {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    }
    .row.no-gutters {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    }
    .col {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    }
    .row.no-gutters .col {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    }
```

My problem is, I want the block to be row, not to be vertical, as you can see in this picture
[image: picture about my problem]

Here is my design, as you can see, the block is horizontal [image: picture design]

So, could you please help me to solve this problem? How can I make it to be horizontal? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Define a width for your `course-items` and it should work just fine. I made it the same width as your height, for a perfect square.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .col {
      text-align: center;

      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .course-item {
      background-color: orange;
      height: 260px;
      width: 260px;
    }

    h1 {
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 260px;
    }



    .row {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-left: -4px;
      margin-right: -4px;
    }

    .row.no-gutters {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .col {
      padding-left: 4px;
      padding-right: 4px;
    }
</style>
</head>
  <body>
  <div class="grid wide container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col l-3">
            <div class="course-item">
                <h1>course 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l-3">
            <div class="course-item">
                <h1>course 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l-3">
            <div class="course-item">
                <h1>course 3</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l-3">
            <div class="course-item">
                <h1>course 4</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but when I copy your code, it became like this https://flic.kr/p/2mT5qbA, I copied the first code to the grid.css file and the second code to the grid_system.html file, so what's wrong ? could you please help me to solve this problem ? Thank you for your time

Comment: @nguyencuc2286 doesn't appear your CSS is parsing or being applied in your browser. Apply the CSS to the `head` in the index file and only use that. See the adjusted answer with the styles in the head.

Comment: thank you, your answer is greate, I have been upvoted your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

(probably optional, but as it isn't clear how it is currently configured, in `.row { ... }` use `flex-flow: row wrap;` instead of `flex-wrap: wrap;`).

In `.col { ... }` add `flex: 1 0 auto;`.

Experiment with the `1 0` in there to adjust the grow/shrink (`1 1` or `0 0` may be preferable depending on your desires).